# Check SCP credentials with SFTP?

Tags: ssh, sftp, scp

I would like to just check SCP credentials but not actually copying anything. This is (to my knowledge) not possible with this command (ssh-ing is not allowed). Question: Is it always possible to check this via SFTP?

Is it possible for ssh settings to allow SCP but not SFTP (in which case I could not check the credentials with the latter).

Comment: might have been more of a "superuser" or "serverfault" question...

Comment: `sftp` for `openssh-server` can be disabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by disabling `Subsystem sftp`.

Comment: You can test credentials by running `scp /path/to/verysmallfile remoteuser@remotehost:/dev/null`.

Comment: @alvits: can you write this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to disable SFTP. In `openssh-server`, there is a config file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` that contains the line:

```
# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

By commenting it, it will practically disable sftp (the default)

To test credentials using `scp` you can run it as:

```
scp /path/to/verysmallfile remoteuser@remotehost:/dev/null
```

The command will return 0 on success and non-zero on failure.